# Add number of duplicate rows in a datatable to a new column

Tags: c#

I need to identify the duplicate columns in the table and add a new column with the number of duplicate column. Thanks in advance
Here is the table that needs to be edited.

[image]

resultant table:

[image]

Comment: not too sure what you're asking ...

Comment: Create a view in the database and then just show that as a single table with C#.

Comment: I need to count the number of duplicate columns in the 2nd table and add the duplicated number to the resultant table as a separate column as shown above

Comment: This is a part of a complex program ..what i need to do is count the number of duplicates. Can you please tell me how to get the query please. I cant find the way to connect a query to my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, try something like this:

```
SELECT FirstName, COUNT(*) FROM FirstNames GROUP BY FirstName
```

Comment: hi, thanks i was able to get the required result from this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want LinQ, and remembering to include using `System.Linq;` at the top of your file, try this:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            string[] data = new String[] {"john","john","mike","ann","ann","ann"};

            var results = data.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => new {name = g.Key, count = g.Count()});

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} occurred {1} times...", result.name, result.count);
            }


            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
void tables()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("Name") });
        dt.Rows.Add("John");
        dt.Rows.Add("Mike");
        dt.Rows.Add("Ann");
        dt.Rows.Add("Sam");
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("Name") });
        dt1.Rows.Add("John");
        dt1.Rows.Add("John");
        dt1.Rows.Add("Mike");
        dt1.Rows.Add("Ann");
        dt1.Rows.Add("Ann");
        dt1.Rows.Add("Ann");
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Available"), new DataColumn("Count") });
        int count = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            count = dt1.Select("Name='" + r[0].ToString() + "'").Count();
            if (count > 0)
                dt2.Rows.Add(r[0].ToString(), "available", count.ToString());
            else
                dt2.Rows.Add(r[0].ToString(), "unavailable", count.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thx for the answer - it does help! the DataTable dt is the eventual result we are after along with the counts - as i understand it your answer presumes it's existence in order to get the counts.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ:

```
table.GroupBy (t => t.Name).Select (t => new {Name = t.Key, Count = t.Count ()})
```

Assuming:

- `table` is a collection that contains your first table
- `Name` is the name of the column that contains the names